# Como correlacionar 2 diferentes txt em python?

Tags: python

Dados de entrada:

```
Primeiro txt
77777777777777777777
Id x y
1 6655.5 -3132.0
2 1122.3 -1234.0
3 4455.6 -5678.9

Segundo txt
Id e n z 
1 111 222 333
2 444 555 666
3 777 888 999

Resultado qual eu preciso: 
7777777777777
1 6655.5 -3132.0 111 222 333
2 1122.3 -1234.0 444 555 666
3 4455.6 -5678.9 777 888 999
```

O que eu fiz até o momento somente junta 2 arquivos, porém somente arquivos com mesmo número de linhas, segue o código:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('text2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    f1_text = f1.read().splitlines()
    f2_text = f2.read().splitlines()
with open('text3.txt', 'w+') as f3:
    for i, item in enumerate(f1_text):
        value1 = f1_text[i].split(None, 1)[1].rstrip('\n')
        value2 = f2_text[i].split(None, 1)[1].rstrip('\n')
        if i == 0:
            i = 'Id'
        f3.write(str(i) + ' ' + value1 + ' ' + value2 + '\n')

with open('text3.txt', 'r') as f3:
    print(f3.read())
```

Já tentei fazer algumas modificações, porém nada do que preciso. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar nesse problema eu agradeceria.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi que você precisa juntar dois (ou mais) arquivos txt.

Pensei nesta forma:

Primeiro leia o `arquivo_1` e salve em uma `lista_1`.

Depois leia o `arquivo_2` e salve em uma `lista_2`.

Por último `merge_lista` recebe as duas listas e salva no `arquivo_novo`

```
arquivo_1, arquivo_2 = "arquivo_1.txt", "arquivo_2.txt"

def ler_arquivo(arquivo):

        lista=[]

        arq = open(arquivo, "r")

        for linha in arq :

                lista.append(linha)

        arq.close()

        return lista


lista_1 = ler_arquivo(arquivo_1)

lista_1.append("\n")

lista_2 = ler_arquivo(arquivo_2)


merge_lista = lista_1.copy()

merge_lista.extend(lista_2)


arq = open("arquivo_novo.txt", 'w')

arq.writelines(merge_lista)

arq.close()
```

Saída:

```
Texto do arquivo um.
Texto do arquivo um.
Texto do arquivo um.
Texto do arquivo dois.
Texto do arquivo dois.
Texto do arquivo dois.
```

Comment: sim, eu preciso juntar dois arquivos, porém precisa ser como no exemplo do resultado a junção por linhas e apagando as descrições das colunas. Agradeço a ajuda amigo, tentarei trabalhar com a ideia de listas agora

Comment: Pode utilizar o `linha.strip("\n")` se não quiser a quebra de página. Outra dica seria `linha.replace("nome_coluna","")` para sumir com o nome das colunas. Se precisar de ajuda estou a disposição. Se a minha resposta te ajudou, peço por gentileza que marque como certa. Boa sorte!